# How to delete Javascript created class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I have some code:

```
let new_user = new User({
    username: 'someone'
}, isValid => {
    if (!isValid) {
        // I need to delete this user class
    }
})
```

I tried to do `new_user = null`, but that doesn't work

Comment: JavaScript is a garbage-collected language. You cannot explicitly delete anything. If it's unused, the GC will take care of it. How do you know that setting the reference to `null` "doesn't work" anyway?

Comment: *"...but that doesn't work..."* What are you seeing that makes you believe it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to do `new_user = null`, but that doesn't work

Yes, it does, provided `new_user` is the only reference to that `User` object. Once all references to an object have been released, the object is eligible for garbage collection. (The value doesn't have to be `null`, specifically; just assigning *anything* else to `new_user` releases the reference it used to hold to the object.)

(The details of when and how that happens are up to the implementation of the JavaScript engine, but that's not important and you can't observe it in your code.)

Comment: @MIkle - You'll have to give us more information. For instance: If `User` registers event handlers, then those event handlers likely have a link back to the user, meaning that `new_user` isn't the only reference to the object. But there's none of that in the question, so...